# Не сохраняется в бинарный файл

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

Ну вообщем, данные не сохраняются в бинарный файл

```
struct Student {
    char FirstName[25], SecondName[25], FatherName[25];
    char sex[25], nationality[25];
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
    int Phonenum;
    int PostIndex;
    char country[25], city[25], street[25];
    int numHouse, numApartment, course, group;
    char specialty[35];
}*Stud = NULL;
Student tmp;
int num;
void add_STUD()
{
    int add_num, new_num;
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\tСТВОРЕННЯ НОВОГО ЗАПИСУ\n\n\n\t-Скільки записів Ви бажаєте внести?\n\t-");
    scanf("%d", &add_num);
    getchar();
    new_num = num + add_num;
    Student* new_Stud = (Student*)malloc((new_num) * sizeof(Student));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        new_Stud[i] = Stud[i];
    free(Stud);
    Stud = new_Stud;
    for (int i = num; i < new_num; i++)
    {
        printf("Прізвище - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].FirstName, 25);
        printf("Ім'я - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].SecondName, 25);
        printf("По батькові - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].FatherName, 25);
        printf("Стать - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].sex, 25);
        printf("Національність - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].nationality, 25);
        printf("День народження  - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].Day);
        printf("Місяць народження  - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].Month);
        printf("Рік народження  - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].Year);
        printf("Номер телефону - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].Phonenum);
        printf("Домашня адреса :\n Поштовий індекс - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].PostIndex);
        printf("Країна - ");
        getchar();
        gets_s(Stud[i].country, 25);
        printf("Місто - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].city, 25);
        printf("Вулиця - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].street, 25);
        printf("Спеціальність - ");
        gets_s(Stud[i].specialty, 35);
        printf("Номер будинку - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].numHouse);
        printf("Номер квартири - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].numApartment);
        printf("Курс - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].course);
        printf("Група - ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Stud[i].group);
    }
    num = new_num;
}
void print_STUD() {
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t\t\tВИВЕДЕННЯ МАСИВУ СТРУКТУР НА ЕКРАН\n");
    if (num == 0)
        printf("\t-Спочатку внесіть в структуру записи!\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\tЗапис №:%d", i + 1);
        printf("\nПІБ - %s %s %s\n", Stud[i].FirstName, Stud[i].SecondName, Stud[i].FatherName);
        printf("Стать - %s\n", Stud[i].sex);
        printf("Національність - %s\n", Stud[i].nationality);
        printf("Дата Народження - %d.%d.%d\n", Stud[i].Day, Stud[i].Month, Stud[i].Year);
        printf("Номер телефону - %d\n", Stud[i].Phonenum);
        printf("Поштовий індекс - %d\n", Stud[i].PostIndex);
        printf("Домашня адреса - %s,%s,вул.%s\n", Stud[i].country, Stud[i].city, Stud[i].street);
        printf("Спеціальність, Курс, Група - %s, %d, %d \n", Stud[i].specialty, Stud[i].course, Stud[i].group);
    }
    printf("\t-Натисніть будь-яку клавішу для виходу до меню");
    _getch();
}
void save_fileSTUD(Student* Stud, int num) {
    FILE* f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        fwrite(&Stud[i], sizeof(Student), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}
void load_fileSTUD() {
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info.bin", "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Файл не знайдено!\n");
        return;
    }
    fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    Student* new_Stud = (Student*)malloc(num * sizeof(Student));
    fread(new_Stud, sizeof(Student), num, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(Stud);
    Stud = new_Stud;
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int num, a = 1;
    load_fileSTUD();
    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\tМЕНЮ\n\n\n1) Створення нового запису;\n2) Виведення масиву структур на екран;\n3) Пошук запису за параметром;\n4) Редагування даних;\n5) Видалення запису із маси-ву;\n6) Сортування масиву структур за вибраними параметрами");
        printf("\n\t-Яку функцію Ви бажаєте обрати?(0 - вихід із програми)\n\t-");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        switch (num) {
        case 0: a = 0; break;
        case 1: add_STUD(); break;
        case 2: print_STUD(); break;
        case 3: Search_STUD(); break;
        case 4: edit_STUD(); break;
        case 5: del_STUD_parametr(); break;
        case 6: sort_STUD_parametr(); break;
        default: printf("Помилка: Невірне значення!\n"); break;
        }
    } while (a != 0);
    save_fileSTUD(Stud, num);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем передавать *Stud в функцию, когда этот указатель у вас глобальный?

Comment: Опишите проблему конкретнее, что вы пробовали? Что не получилось? Какая ошибка вылазит?

Comment: я вожу данные о студенте и они должны сохранять в файл Stud_Info.bin, но оно просто не сохраняется

Comment: Не сохраняется вообще ничего? Проверьте, правильно ли вы ввели данные в *Stud. Вы можете с помощью отладки Visual Studio посмотреть, на каком моменте все идет не так

Comment: Вы определённо вводите неправильно, лучше не пользуйтесь указателями

Comment: "Не удалось загрузить средство чтения PDB-символов" написано в отладке

Comment: На каком моменте кода? Дополните свой вопрос

Comment: У вас пример не минимальный. Чтоб протестировать - надо сидеть и вводить всякую фигню. сделайте минимальный приме (а там может и сами увидите, где ошибка).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, если не сработает - проблема в передаче данных

```
void save_fileSTUD(Student* Stud, int num) {
    FILE* f = fopen("C:\\practuka\\Stud_Info.bin", "wb");
    if (!f) {
        return;
    }
    fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(Stud, sizeof(Student), num, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Предпоследний аргумент `fwrite()` - количество записываемых блоков, то есть, если num есть размер массива, то можно обойтись без цикла

Comment: не сработало...